# LDAP connection for jupyterhub

Tags: ldap, jupyter, openldap, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I want to configure LDAP connection for Jupyterhub, but i don't know what are the setting to use as there are so many, I tried using this as reference https://github.com/jupyterhub/ldapauthenticator and https://github.com/hansohn/jupyterhub-ldap-authenticator .Still i am not able to figure out which settings are most, it would be helpful if you could identify which are must and how the LDAP login works in jupyterhub.

If you have any opensource LDAP connection working example, please share.